# proxy server to use ssh -D port

Tags: ssh, proxy, squid

By using ssh like `ssh userB@serverB -D 0.0.0.0:6060` , we bind ssh to the 6060 port of current server (serverA).
I can connect to serverA port 6060 using Socks5 client (no auth).

There are 2 problems:

1. I would like to be able to use the opened port using http proxy client (not just socks client)
2. there is no authentication

I tried to run different proxy servers to handle both problems.

- I used `Dante` but it needs a plugin for redirect which is not free.
- Running `shadow-socks` didn't help.
- I tried to use `squid` to redirect all incoming requests of squid port (3128) to 6060 port but couldn't handle configs and gives errors.

> **squid conf:**  
> #acl port_1 localport 3128 
> acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 
> http_port 3128 
> http_access allow all 
> cache_peer 0.0.0.0 parent 6060 0 no-query default 
> #cache_peer_access host_1 allow port_1 
> never_direct allow all